# How do I change my JAVA_HOME permanently Mac User?

Tags: java, zsh, java-home

So when I run

```
> echo $JAVA_HOME                                                       
> /Users/xxx/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
```

However in my *.zshrc* I have set it to export `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`

so every time I need to use Java or open new terminal I have to source *.zshrc*

I'm 100% sure I'm using zshrc

```
% echo $0 
/bin/zsh
```

Also this is how My ZSHRC is loooking

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: It could be this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/397299/zsh-cant-see-and-doesnt-load-the-zshrc-startup-file

Comment: If you no longer want to use `sdkman` (which I have no idea why you wouldn't want to); remove `[[ -s "/Users/xxx/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/Users/xxx/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"` at the end of `$HOME/.zshrc`.

Comment: In other words `source "/Users/xxx/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh` is overriding the `JAVA_HOME` that you set earlier in the `.zshrc` file?

Comment: This helpful tool works well on macOS: https://sdkman.io/

Comment: @StephenC, correct I don't know where this could happen

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have removed it when I uninstall it, yet something is still overriding it

Comment: You have several (at least one anyway) lines that reset `JAVA_HOME` after `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`. The last one "wins".

Comment: By default, any **interactive** zsh sources .zshrc automatically on startup, unless you are overriding this behaviour (using the variable `ZDOTDIR`), so your approach should work. However note that this does not occur for non-interactive shells, but since you have exported your variable, this should not do any harm (unless you are running scripts from i.e. cron). I suggest that you trace a complete startup of your zsh with `-x` turned on to see all the places where your JAVA_HOME gets reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation of being able to permanently set JAVA_HOME in your .zshrc file is correct.  It's how most JVM developers do it.

If zsh is your shell, then `.zshrc` will run automatically every time you open a new terminal, *unless something is interfering with it*.

To find out what is interfering, I suggest starting with an empty `.zshrc` with a first line of `echo ".zshrc ran"`.  This will print to the console everytime you open a new terminal, proving it's being run.

Then start adding back parts from your current `.zshrc` to see which part is causing the unwanted JAVA_HOME behavior.

Comment: I used to use bash profile ( had the same issue) and thats why I moved to .zshrc to have a new start, so definitely something is interfering with it but Idk how or where to look.